# Building an IDS (Special considerations for speed)

Tags: speed, intrusion-prevention

### Background

I plan to build a Network Intrusion Detection System, (using a dual-homed desktop pc running Debian and Snort) that will sit between my ISP's router (home LAN) and an additional router (security LAN), for the purpose of learning more about network security)

### My Question

Are there any special considerations I should make for the network hardware used in the desktop? Will using a desktop without a special NIC introduce lag? Should I opt for a special dual homed NIC or will two standard NIC's work well enough?

Comment: "dual-home" means connecting to two (or more) networks (read: ISPs) A "dual-port" nic has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I will be connectiong two networks, as I said Home LAN will be the ISP router, it will connect to my dual homed PC which will be acting as an IDS/homeserver, on the other port will be connected a second router (Security LAN). I want to monitor the traffic entering and leaving this network. For this to work my IDS/Server will need to be dual homed and have two nic cards to connect to two networks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any special considerations I should make for the network hardware used in the desktop?

Not at the speeds common to "home users". You may be surprised by the hardware inside many "big iron" routers. (hint: they use the same NIC hardware found in everything.) What makes them "fast" is the routing and switching hardware. And that's present in a small percentage devices.

> Should I opt for a special dual homed NIC...

Multi-*port* NICs just reduce the number of slots being used. Use what you have, or get what ever your budget allows.  Keep in mind the bus speed of the card(s) if using multi-port cards. (i.e. PCIe x1 is 2.5G)

Answer (score 0):

> Will using a desktop without a special NIC introduce lag?

Not at anything you'll be running through it, but I've seen some desktop MOBO NICs start to fluke out when you try to push around 700 Mbps at them.